# Temporary loading image and image selection when clicking thumbnails using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have used the following code to switch out images when a user clicks on the thumbnail. The only problem is that it sometimes take a little while to load the large picture after the person clicks on the thumbnail. Is there a way to have a temporary loading image either appear over the thumbnail or the main image to show that it is loading the image when they click on the thumbnail? This temporary loading picture would then go away after the picture is loaded. Another option would be to have the thumbnail image lower its opacity when it is the selected picture. I tried for longer than I would like to admit, but couldn't figure it out.

```
<div class="mainphoto">
    <img id="main-image" src="http://www.website.com/large/1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <table class="additionalphotostable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/spacer.gif" class="full" onclick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/1.jpg';" style="background: url(http://www.website.com/small/1.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;width: 48px;height: 48px;" />
             <!--This picture structure is different because the thumbnail is not the same size as the rest. I am using CSS to make it appear to be the same size by placing it as a background image-->
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/small/2.jpg" class="full" onClick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/2.jpg';" />
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/small/3.jpg" class="full" onClick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/3.jpg';" />
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/small/4.jpg" class="full" onClick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/4.jpg';" />
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/small/5.jpg" class="full" onClick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/5.jpg';" />
            </td>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="http://www.website.com/small/6.jpg" class="full" onClick="document.getElementById('main-image').src='http://www.website.com/large/6.jpg';" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely need JS. Why not make a JS function `on.click` that `show`s a display of an animated `gif` based on `$('.additionalphotostable').on('click',function() {` and `.hide`s it after `this` image is loaded?

Comment: Just set an `id` with a `predefined` value with your load bar.

Comment: @NicholasHazel that is what I was trying to do, but I could never figure out the code to have it do all of these: change picture, show temp picture, and show active thumbnail. I am hoping someone can help me combine all of these.

Comment: Hmmm, lemme fiddle away.

Comment: I will fix this, as it's a pretty simple problem. Girl just came over. Going to have to rehash for tomorrow.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Thank you for your help, I understand the girl thing.

Comment: @NicholasHazel - Not sure if you are still able to help. No one else has responded.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Totally forgot about this post.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is you are targeting the `same ID` for your images.

`onClick="document.getElementById('main-image')`

Only 1 `ID` should exist per page.

---

Here is a very simple way to create a "loading" image.

#### Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/x3vc7/4/

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://www.wall75.com/images/2013/08/image-explosion-colors-background-beautiful-263613.jpg" />

<img id="loader" src="http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/gd/image/1389/31/1389311265704.gif" />
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
}
#loader {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    display:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    });
});
```